# How can I keep history of data changes in one excel workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, macros

A user posted this in a [different question](https://superuser.com/a/941653/427317):

> Here's some code that will watch the range `A1:G12` on whatever sheet has the code in it. If `r` is the row that was changed, then the code
>   will copy everything from Ar:Gr into a sheet whose code name is
>   shtLog. (Code name is the name shown in VBA, not the name on the tab
>   you see in Excel.) This should get you moving in the right direction.
>
> ```
>  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)    
>     Dim r As Integer
>     Dim c As Integer
>     Dim arr(1 To 1, 1 To 12)
>     If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:G12")) Is Nothing Then
>         r = Target.Row
>         For c = 1 To 12
>             arr(1, c) = Cells(r, c).Value
>         Next
>         With shtLog
>             .Range(.Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 12)) = arr
>         End With
>     End If
> End Sub
> ```

However, Although I can see the code I have used in a module and in the VBA Editor I can't see, find, select or run the macro so I have no idea how to get the logger to work.

Would anyone know how to get the code to work so it starts recording in the designated sheet?

Answer (score 2):

Don't put it in a module.

This macro is invoked automatically every time a change happens in a worksheet, as you can see from its first line: `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`.

In the VBA Editor, on the left side, double click the worksheet that you want to have the macro (i.e. the worksheet on which you want to track changes on) and then paste the code on the right side.

If you want to debug it follow these steps:

1. Put a *breakpoint* in the first line of the code, clicking on the left side of the line. A brown dot will apear and the line will be highlighted in the same color, like this:
   [image]

---

2. Make a change in the worksheet, for example putting a value in a cell. The code will execute and stop in the *breakpoint*, in our case in the first line, it will be highlighted in yellow, like this:

[image]

---

3. To execute the code line by line press <kbd>F8</kbd>. It will help you to see what is happenning on every step.
4. After you have done the debug you can remove the *breakpoint* clicking on the brown spot.

Keep in mind that the macro put values in a worksheet called `shtLog`, you have to create a worksheet called like that or change the name in the code to avoid the error of not finding the destination worksheet.

Comment: I will give it a try - appreciated.